# show that $e^P \approx I + 1.718*P$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I know that : Let ${P}\in R^{nxn}$   $$e^P = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\frac{P^k}{k!}}$$

My question is : Let $P \in R^{nxn}$ be a projection. Show that $$e^P \approx I + 1.718*P$$

I have no idea about number 1.718 ?

Comment: Hint: $1.718$ is about $e-1$.

Comment: @Thiê After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 6):

Using the fact that for a projection matrix, $P^k=P$ for positive $k$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\frac{P^k}{k!}}
&=I+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\frac{P}{k!}}\\
&=I+P\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{k!}}-1\right)\\[9pt]
&=I+(e-1)P
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh, I forgot that property. It's really simple ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If $P $ is a projection then

$$P^2=P^3=...=P $$

Comment: I forgot that property of projection. Thank you very much !